# I am the following error with my laravel app that is an azure web app

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a Laravel application deployed on Azure Web App. However, I'm encountering an unexpected error: "No route registered for '/build/assets/app-c50f6abb.js',."  Anytime i try to get click on js or css link that is what i get.

I should note that I don't have admin privileges on the account;
I'm just a user.

For reference, I've included my Nginx configuration below, in case it provides some insights:

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot/public; # Changed for Laravel
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  index.com www.index.com;
    port_in_redirect off;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {            
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # Changed for Laravel
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html; # Commented out for Laravel so that Laravel debug mode pages are shown
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run npm run build  or prod?

Comment: I did. I see the files on the server

Comment: are you using vite/mix? If so which one? Do you see the mix_manifest.json under public folder? Do you see the assets in your public folder(if you use mix or vite)

Comment: I am utilizing Vite. Inside the public directory, there's a build subfolder which contains an assets folder with the relevant files. there is manifest.json in the build folder

Comment: Do you see the value `app-c50f6abb.js` inside the manifest.json? It should be an object with key/value pair. Does the file with value `app-c50f6abb.js` exist?

Comment: value is something like `js/filename.js : js/filename.cachename.js`

Comment: Hey in the file it is   "file": "assets/app-c50f6abb.js",

Comment: does `file` exist in the correct directory? file should also be `app-c50f6abb.js` since you are using filename caching. not version caching.

Comment: Though if your manifest.json's value is something like `js/file.js: js/file.js?id=somehashcode`, then this will work right out of the box.